# IndexError: index 29 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 14

Tags: python

I don't know why my lens cannot read all the columns. I print the len(data) but it only read 15 instead of 39. How can I make it read all the columns.

```
import numpy as np
import warnings

#warnings.simplefilter('always',Warning)


############################### start: define here ###################################
kkfile      = "scan_run_01.txt"     
outfile ="masslist.out"

############################### end: define here ###################################
n_cols = len(kkfile)

Omega =np.loadtxt(kkfile,usecols=np.arange(1, n_cols))[:,1]
LR =np.loadtxt(kkfile,usecols=np.arange(1, n_cols))[:,0]        
tot_sigmav=np.loadtxt(kkfile,usecols=np.arange(1, n_cols))[:,29]
BB_sigmav=np.loadtxt(kkfile,usecols=np.arange(1, n_cols))[:,23]
UU_sigmav=np.loadtxt(kkfile,usecols=np.arange(1, n_cols))[:,18]

print(n_cols)

line1='  Omega     LR    Tot_sigmav    BB_sigmav  UU_sigmav  mass '

np.savetxt(outfile,np.c_[Omega,LR,tot_sigmav,BB_sigmav,UU_sigmav],'%25.15e', header=line1)

print "\nextracted mass had been print to'%s'."%outfile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my error by change stop interval to `np.arange`

```
import numpy as np
import warnings

#warnings.simplefilter('always',Warning)


############################### start: define here ###################################
kkfile      = "scan_run_01.txt"     
outfile ="masslist.out"

############################### end: define here ##################################

Omega =np.loadtxt(kkfile,usecols=np.arange(1, 40))[:,1]
LR =np.loadtxt(kkfile,usecols=np.arange(1, 40))[:,0]        
tot_sigmav=np.loadtxt(kkfile,usecols=np.arange(1, 40))[:,29]
BB_sigmav=np.loadtxt(kkfile,usecols=np.arange(1, 40))[:,23]
UU_sigmav=np.loadtxt(kkfile,usecols=np.arange(1, 40))[:,18]


line1='  Omega     LR    Tot_sigmav    BB_sigmav  UU_sigmav  mass '

np.savetxt(outfile,np.c_[Omega,LR,tot_sigmav,BB_sigmav,UU_sigmav],'%25.15e', header=line1)

print "\nextracted mass had been print to'%s'."%outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `n_cols` to the length of the string "scan_run_01.txt".  I don't know what scan_run_01.txt looks like since you didn't include it, but surely using the length of the filename as the number of columns is not what you actually want.  Presumably you want the length of the data within kkfile?  Or maybe the length of the first line?  Or maybe the length of the first line split by some deliminator?

```
with open(kkfile, 'r') as stream:
   content = stream.read()

# Change this to get the length of what you actually want.
n_cols = len(content)
```

Just guessing that's what you intended.

Comment: yup I want the n_cols to the length of the data in kkfile, to be precisely the same number columns. I try to use your suggestions but I got error: ```IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: I'd suggest updating your question with the new code and error and a sample output for kkfile so we know what's actually running. Lots of different input could cause you to have an index error.  But we don't know that input is.  And a stack trace would be nice so we know where the index is happening.  The less we have to guess the better the answers will be.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I already understand my error. when you said that I set my n_cols to the length of the string " scan_run_01.txt". That's  why my size data only 15 instead 40. So, I need to set my n_cols to the length of my data column. Since I already knew my data columns length. I just change the stop interval to the data columns length.